# Equivalence relations on the set [3].

Tags: equivalence-relations

Consider the set $[3]$ and the equivalence relation defined by the graph: $$\{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}.$$ I know this is an equivalence relation because it is symmetric, transitive, and reflexive. My professor says $1\sim 2$ since $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, but $1$ is not equivalent to $3$? Why is this the case?

Comment: $(1,3)$ is not one of the related pairs you gave us.   Just to be clear $1\sim 2$ because $(1,2)$ is one of the pairs you gave us, not for the reasons you gave.

Comment: $1\sim2$ because $(1,2)\in R$ but $1\not\sim3$ because $(1,3)\not\in R$

Comment: Are your sure that your professor really said "1~ 2 since ~ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive"?  That is why it is an equivalence relation but  **not** why  "1~ 2".  1~ 2 because (1, 2) is in that set,  1≁3 because (1, 3) is not in the set.

Answer (score 1):

If $1$ were equivalent to $3$, then $(1,3)$ would be in $R$. Since $(1,3) \not \in R$, $1 \not \sim 3$. The equivalence of elements when you know all ordered pairs $(x,y) \in R$ is not going to be something you attempt to draw out from the properties of equivalence relations; it'll be quite clear since you'll know outright whether they're related or not.

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*